# Resque-scheduler dynamic reports "schedule empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am trying to use resque-scheduler gem to schedule jobs I installed the gem (V 2.0.0d) and followed the info written on github
this is my resque.rake file

```
# Resque tasks
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks' 



namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque_scheduler'
    require 'resque/scheduler'     



# you probably already have this somewhere
Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'

# The schedule doesn't need to be stored in a YAML, it just needs to
# be a hash.  YAML is usually the easiest.
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")


# If you want to be able to dynamically change the schedule,
# uncomment this line.  A dynamic schedule can be updated via the
# Resque::Scheduler.set_schedule (and remove_schedule) methods.
# When dynamic is set to true, the scheduler process looks for 
# schedule changes and applies them on the fly.
# Note: This feature is only available in >=2.0.0.
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true



 end
end
```

but every time I run `rake resque:scheduler` it says

Loading Schedule
  Schedule empty! Set Resque.schedule
  Schedules Loaded

If I remove `Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true` the schedule gets loaded correctly but I need to set this option as the schedule changes over time

Comment: Couldn't get it to run but used another way, I just wrote script to kill the scheduler process and then start it again every time I change the file, may be this is not the best solution but it works.
Leaving the question open if someone could make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by placing the following code:

```
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
```

just above the following:

```
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
```

For more information, have a look at https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/issues/115